# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character inspite of encoding to utf-8

Tags: python

I am converting my XML documents to plain text. There is a directory containing XML files and one python file to compile. 
I have opened my XML files as:

`with open(file, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:`

then wrote in another file the contents of `f`:

```
for items in xmllist:
    fx.write(items)
```

but it gives me the error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2009' in position 25: character maps to

Comment: What version of Python? What type is `items`?

Comment: @Muposat they are items of a list containing xml content

Comment: you can add `errors='ignore'` to `open()` [read the doc about other options](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: @Muposat i tried it : `with open(file, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:` but it still gives me the error

Comment: @Muposat '\u2009' is thin space but I'm checking the xml document and there is none

Comment: Well the error happens when you write to file `fx`, but to fix the error you change the mode of opening file `f` for reading. This is not the same file handle.